# Loading geoJSON Markers from API - React Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

Leaflet and using GeoJSON. I am trying to get the markers from a fetched GeoJSON API to render on the map, once the data is stored on the state. I have tried using the marker component to display the markers from the API but nothing is rendering to the page. I am open to use the marker component or any other way to display the markers. Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      location: {
        lat: 51.505,
        lng: -0.09
      },
      zoom: 2,
      bikes: null,
      haveUsersLocation: false,
    };

 componentWillMount() {
    fetch(
      "https://bikewise.org:443/api/v2/locations/markers?proximity_square=10"
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ bikes: data }));
  }

 render() {
    const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng];

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Menu />
        <Map className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />

          <GeoJSON addData={this.state.bikes} /> 

          {this.state.haveUsersLocation ? (
            <Marker position={position} icon={myIcon}>
              <Popup>Your current location</Popup>
            </Marker>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason Marker component never gets called because `this.state.haveUsersLocation` is always false and you are not setting it to true anywhere in the component. If you want to render Marker component only when `haveUsersLocation` is true then you need to change `haveUsersLocation` to true to render Marker otherwise remove the condition

You need to make haveUsersLocation it to true in componentWillMount and Marker will render successfully

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch(
      "https://bikewise.org:443/api/v2/locations/markers?proximity_square=10"
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => this.setState({ haveUsersLocation: true, bikes: response.data.features }));
  }
```

To force react to re-render the GeoJSON data you need to pass some data-uniq key to component. Check below github issue for more details

```
   <GeoJSON key={`geojson-01`} addData={this.state.bikes} />
```

https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/332#issuecomment-304228071

Also a unique key needs to be added for Marker as well

```
   {this.state.haveUsersLocation ? (
        <Marker key={`marker-01`} position={position} icon={myIcon}>
          <Popup>Your current location</Popup>
        </Marker>
      ) :  ""}
```

Comment: The ternary operator updates the haveUsersLocation state and the initial marker that I create displays just fine but I can't display markers from the API.

Comment: @Shawn I have updated my answer please give a try now

Comment: You need to set response.data.features to bikes

Comment: @Think-Twice Or, alternatively, instead of altering the response, just change the GeoJSON tag? `<GeoJSON addData={this.state.bikes.features} />`

Comment: @AussieJoe yeah agreed that is valid too

Comment: @AussieJoe thank you! I am getting back an array of objects from <GeoJSON addData.. /> but nothing is rendering.

Comment: @Shawn you need to add unique key to GeoJSON only then it will render the data. Check my updated answer